# Using Regex to cut string to 2 parts

Tags: database

I have a string like this `[Enity:Equipment]@[Property:Space]`

And i want 2 matches.

1: match Equipment

2 match Space

i cant figure out.

I have tried this

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged the question with the "database" tag, and as Oracle is one of databases, see whether such a `regexp_substr` helps; basically, it returns 2nd and 4th *word* from the input string, presuming that format is exactly as you put it.

```
SQL> with test(col) as
  2    (select '[Enity:Equipment]@[Property:Space]' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 2) as equipment,
  4         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 4) as space
  5  from test;

EQUIPMENT SPACE
--------- -----
Equipment Space

SQL>
```